# PGFplots - label each group plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

In this group plot how do I add labels to individual graphs. I want to label each graph as (a), (b), (c)...

```
 \documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
        \usepackage{pgfplots}
        \usetikzlibrary{matrix}
        \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
        \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
        \begin{document}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size= 2 by 4},height=5cm,width=6.4cm]
                        \nextgroupplot[title=type1,ylabel={Range1 }]
                                        \addplot[blue] {x};\label{plots:plot1}
                                        \addplot[red] {x^2};\label{plots:plot2}
                                        \addplot[green] {2*x};\label{plots:plot3}
                                        \coordinate (top) at (rel axis cs:0,1);% coordinate at top of the first plot
                        \nextgroupplot[title=type2]
                                        \addplot[blue]{x};
                        \nextgroupplot[ylabel={Range2 }]
                                        \addplot[blue]{x};
                        \nextgroupplot
                                        \addplot[blue]{x};
                        \nextgroupplot[ylabel={Range3 }]
                                        \addplot[blue]{x};
                        \nextgroupplot
                                        \addplot[blue]{x};
                        \nextgroupplot[xlabel={Number of Threads},ylabel={Range4 }]
                                        \addplot[blue]{x};
                        \nextgroupplot[xlabel={Number of Threads}]
                                        \addplot[blue]{x};
                                        \coordinate (bot) at (rel axis cs:1,0);% coordinate at bottom of the last plot
                \end{groupplot}
                \path (top-|current bounding box.west)-- 
                            node[anchor=south,rotate=90] {throughput} 
                            (bot-|current bounding box.west);
        % legend
        \path (top|-current bounding box.north)--
                    coordinate(legendpos)
                    (bot|-current bounding box.north);
        \matrix[
                matrix of nodes,
                anchor=south,
                draw,
                inner sep=0.2em,
                draw
            ]at([yshift=1ex]legendpos)
            {
                \ref{plots:plot1}& curve 1&[5pt]
                \ref{plots:plot2}& curve2&[5pt]
                \ref{plots:plot3}& curve 3\\};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{document}
```

output:
[image: output]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `group names` key and with the help of positioning`library` ad a node below every plot like:

```
\node[below = 0.5cm of my plots c1r1.south] {(a)};
```

Here `c1r1` means `column 1 and row 1`.

```
 \documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
        \usepackage{pgfplots}
        \usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
        \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
        \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
        \begin{document}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{groupplot}[group style={group name=my plots,group size= 2 by 4,vertical sep=1.5cm },height=5cm,width=6.4cm]
                        \nextgroupplot[title=type1,ylabel={Range1 }]
                                        \addplot[blue] {x};\label{plots:plot1}
                                        \addplot[red] {x^2};\label{plots:plot2}
                                        \addplot[green] {2*x};\label{plots:plot3}
                                        \coordinate (top) at (rel axis cs:0,1);% coordinate at top of the first plot
                        \nextgroupplot[title=type2]
                                        \addplot[blue]{x};
                        \nextgroupplot[ylabel={Range2 }]
                                        \addplot[blue]{x};
                        \nextgroupplot
                                        \addplot[blue]{x};
                        \nextgroupplot[ylabel={Range3 }]
                                        \addplot[blue]{x};
                        \nextgroupplot
                                        \addplot[blue]{x};
                        \nextgroupplot[xlabel={Number of Threads},ylabel={Range4 }]
                                        \addplot[blue]{x};
                        \nextgroupplot[xlabel={Number of Threads}]
                                        \addplot[blue]{x};
                                        \coordinate (bot) at (rel axis cs:1,0);% coordinate at bottom of the last plot
                \end{groupplot}
                \node[below = 0.5cm of my plots c1r1.south] {(a)};
                \node[below = 0.5cm of my plots c2r1.south] {(b)};
                \node[below = 0.5cm of my plots c1r2.south] {(c)};
                \node[below = 0.5cm of my plots c2r2.south] {(d)};
                \node[below = 0.5cm of my plots c1r3.south] {(e)};
                \node[below = 0.5cm of my plots c2r3.south] {(f)};
                \node[below = 0.9cm of my plots c1r4.south] {(g)};
                \node[below = 0.9cm of my plots c2r4.south] {(h)};
                \path (top-|current bounding box.west)--
                            node[anchor=south,rotate=90] {throughput}
                            (bot-|current bounding box.west);
        % legend
        \path (top|-current bounding box.north)--
                    coordinate(legendpos)
                    (bot|-current bounding box.north);
        \matrix[
                matrix of nodes,
                anchor=south,
                draw,
                inner sep=0.2em,
                draw
            ]at([yshift=1ex]legendpos)
            {
                \ref{plots:plot1}& curve 1&[5pt]
                \ref{plots:plot2}& curve2&[5pt]
                \ref{plots:plot3}& curve 3\\};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{document}
```

[image]

You may have to adjust the `vertical sep` so as to accommodate these nodes like I did (1.5cm).