# Wrong font scaling using when groupplot, tikzscale and fillbetween, maybe a bug (?)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween, groupplots

**Situation:**

I am trying to place one bigger pgfplot at the left side of a figure and four small plots (2x2) on the right half, like this:

```
|--------|----|----|  
|        | P2 | P3 |  
| plot 1 |----|----|  
|        | P4 | P5 |  
|--------|----|----|
```

For this I use two groupplots next to each other as shown here: [Create groupplot 3 x 6](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150980/create-groupplot-3-x-6). I scale them with `tikzscale`, in order to fill the page and still maintain fontsize etc. Furthermore I need to plot one legend above all plots, as explained here: [PGFplots - label each group plots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194477/pgfplots-label-each-group-plots)

**Problem:**

Everything works fine as long as I do not use `fillbetween` in the pgf plot. Here is a MWE that I compile twice with LuaLaTeX under Windows (MiKTeX, all packages are updated), the `fillbetween` commands are commented so far:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{A.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[
  group style={
    group name=left plot,
    group size=1 by 1,
  },
  width=0.45*\textwidth,
  height=6cm,
  xlabel={$x$},
  ylabel={$y$},
  scale only axis,
  xmin=-0.028,
  xmax=0.2222,
  ymin=0.0,
  ymax=0.6666,
  xmajorgrids,
  ymajorgrids,
  axis x line=bottom,
  axis y line=left,
  ]

  \nextgroupplot[]
  \addplot[name path=OneA,solid,color=gray, forget plot] coordinates { (-0.027,0.18) (0.0,0.0) (0.222,0.6666)};

  \addplot [name path=TwoA,solid,color=gray, forget plot] coordinates { (-0.027,0.18) (0.222,0.6666)};

  %\addplot[lightgray, forget plot] fill between[of = OneA and TwoA];

  \addplot coordinates { (0,0.05) (0.05,0.2) (0.15,0.55) (0.2,0.4) }; \label{plot1}
  \addplot coordinates { (0,0.6) (0.05,0.1) (0.15,0.26) (0.2,0.44) }; \label{plot2}
  \addplot coordinates { (0,0.1) (0.05,0.3) (0.15,0.33) (0.2,0.2) }; \label{plot3}
  \addplot coordinates { (0,0.42) (0.05,0.41) (0.15,0.4) (0.2,0.39) }; \label{plot4}
  \addplot coordinates { (0,0.6) (0.05,0.02) (0.15,0.61) (0.2,0.32) }; \label{plot5}

  \end{groupplot}

  \begin{groupplot}[
  group style={
    group name=right plots,
    group size=2 by 2,
    horizontal sep = 1cm,
  },
  width=0.2*\textwidth,
  height=2.1cm,
  scale only axis,
  xmajorgrids,
  ymajorgrids,
  ]
  \nextgroupplot[anchor=north west, at={($(left plot c1r1.north east) + (2cm,0)$)},
  xmin=-0.015,
  xmax=0.08,
  ymin=0.0,
  ymax=0.22,]
  \addplot[name path=OneB,solid,color=gray, forget plot] coordinates { (-0.027,0.18) (0.0,0.0) (0.222,0.6666)};

  \addplot [name path=TwoB,solid,color=gray, forget plot] coordinates { (-0.027,0.18) (0.222,0.6666)};

  %\addplot[lightgray, forget plot] fill between[of = OneB and TwoB];

  \addplot coordinates { (0,0.05) (0.05,0.2) (0.15,0.55) (0.2,0.4) };
  \nextgroupplot[]
  \addplot coordinates { (0,0.05) (0.05,0.2) (0.15,0.55) (0.2,0.4) };
  \nextgroupplot[]
  \addplot coordinates{ (0,0.05) (0.05,0.2) (0.15,0.55) (0.2,0.4) };
  \nextgroupplot[]
  \addplot coordinates { (0,0.05) (0.05,0.2) (0.15,0.55) (0.2,0.4) };
  \end{groupplot}

  % legend
  \path (left plot c1r1.north west|-current bounding box.north)--coordinate(legendpos)(right plots c2r2.south east|-current bounding box.north);
  \matrix[
  matrix of nodes,
  anchor=south,
  draw,
  inner sep=0.2em,
  draw
  ]at([yshift=1ex]legendpos)
  {
    \ref{plot1}& $a=1$&[5pt]
    \ref{plot2}& $a=2$&[5pt]
    \ref{plot3}& Lit\\
    \ref{plot4}& $a=3$&[5pt]
    \ref{plot5}& $a=4$\\
  };

  \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{filecontents}

\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{A.tikz}
\end{document}
```

It produces the (expected) output:
[image: Correct scaling without fillbetween]

When I uncomment the first `fillbetween` command in plot 1, font scaling crashes:

[image: Wrong font scaling with fillbetween]

And things become really scary when I activate `fillbetween` in the first of the four smaller plots (P2). This leads to wrong font scaling and wrong placement of the plot:

[image: Wrong scaling and Placement]

So I am not sure whether this is some kind of bug or whether I am just doing something wrong. Every help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: One more note: It turned out that it works, when I use the `draw` command as `\draw[fill=gray](axis cs:0,0) -- ... -- cycle` but unfortunately the shape is not a triangle in my real case but a more complex region between two paths. The coordinates are stored in a .csv-file, in case there is a possibility to `draw` a path out of these data, that would be a workaround. Unfortunately, I did not yet find a solution to make this work.